# Shared Preferences misplugin

Tags: flutter, dart

i do same exactly as youtube says but in the end i got this error, do you know what is the problem ?

im using flutter 2.8.1 shared_preferences: ^2.0.13

this is the code

```
 class _AppHomeState extends State<AppHome> {
 final Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        Future loadData() async {
            final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
            var stringSet = await prefs.getString('sets');
            List setList = jsonDecode(stringSet!);
            for (var sets in setList) {
              c.setList.add(SetModel().fromJson(sets));
            }
          }
        
          Future saveData() async {
            final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
            List items = c.setList.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
            prefs.setString('sets', jsonEncode(items));
          }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try running**

```
flutter clean
```

see issue [`here`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10912)

Comment: well it works fine after i re debug the app :D

Answer (score 0):

Modify line number 31 as below:

```
final SharedPreferences _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

This will fix your problem.

Comment: well it can't do, because it said = A value of type 'Future<SharedPreferences>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'SharedPreferences'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'SharedPreferences'

Comment: have you tried it, i do not understand what you are telling

Comment: yes, thanks btw don't worry it works fine now it just need to redebug